# Align image added by CSS content tag

Tags: css

I want to add a checkbox to `div` element. It's can be easily done by using `content:before` tag. So this css

```
.btn {
    border: 1px solid #606060;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;

    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 5px #38414d;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #38414d;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 5px #38414d;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
}


.btn:before {
    content:url(http://tinyurl.com/pmrqpon);
}
```

results this button.

[image]

The problem is that this new content element is added by css dynamicly. But i need to place it right in `div` **without changing the position of "BUTTON" text.** How can i achive this?

Comment: You would have to position the pseudo-element absolutely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like this:

```
.btn {
    ...
    position: relative;
}

.btn:before {
    ...
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to position the pseudo-element absolutely.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NNuTm/1/)**

**HTML**

Button

**CSS**

```
.btn {
    border: 1px solid #606060;
    background: #e3e3e3;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;

    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 5px #38414d;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #38414d;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 5px #38414d;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    height: 55px;
    line-height: 55px;
    position:relative;
}

.btn:before {
    content:url(http://tinyurl.com/pmrqpon);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:20%; **(adjust as required)**
}
```